# Verification Status of my application is showing as developer action required in google OAuth consent screen

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-developers-console

I am accessing the Google Calendar API in my application.  I have completed the initial OAuth consent procedures, however it is still showing developer action required and some actions are listed, I am not aware of these actions list items, can anyone help me!

[image: OAuth screen&]

[image: Verification message]

the learn more link shown in status is provided :
[Verification process](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#verification-process)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to verify your app there are some things that you must comply with the key points being

Make sure that your homepage meets the following requirements:

- Your homepage must be publicly accessible, and not behind a sign-in page.
- Your homepage must make clear its relevance to the app you’re verifying.
- Your homepage must be accurate, inclusive, and easily accessible to all users.

Make sure that your app's Privacy Policy meets the following requirements:

- The Privacy Policy must be visible to users, hosted within the domain of your website, and linked from the OAuth consent screen on the Google API Console.
- The Privacy Policy must disclose the manner in which your application accesses, uses, stores, or shares Google user data. Your use of Google user data must be limited to the practices disclosed in your published Privacy Policy.

As well as

Prepare a video that fully demonstrates the OAuth grant process by users and shows, in detail, the usage of sensitive scopes in the app.

By the looks of the messages that you are getting you have not verified your domain or set up the privacy  policy or sent them a video.

Application verification can be a little confusing thats why i put up a video dedicated to it.  It may help you set things up [What you need to know about Google verification in 2021.](https://youtu.be/lzIuNmNX9N8)

Additional reading [OAuth API verificaiton](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will refer the video shared to understand the process

Comment: "The Privacy Policy must disclose the manner in which your application accesses, uses, stores, or shares Google user data. Your use of Google user data must be limited to the practices disclosed in your published Privacy Policy "                                                                 related to this , If i am using only google calendar API ,then what should i add in my privacy policy , the app doesn't store the details . i am attaching a link for OAuth demonstration video :  https://youtu.be/DBz-myj2GlU

Comment: This is unfortunately for us the rules as they stand.   IMO google has chosen to ignore the single user use case when implementing these rules.   Yes you have to go though all of that yes even if you will be the only one using it.    Look around there are some standard privacy policy generators around.